# PQ core for flyback transformer - Why use a PQ core

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, electromagnetism

I m actually considering a board with a flyback transformer and it is a PQ core 26/25 for being precised for an output of 50W. However I read from " Inductor and Flyback - Transformer Design " written by TI, the following sentence :

"Pot cores and PQ cores have small window area in relation to core size, and the window shape is not well suited for flyback transfonners or discontinuous mode inductors"

I know that it is better to have a windows as wide as possible to minimize AC resistance. Nevertheless, I m clearly newby in transformer design, and as regards of my experience I would like to have your opinion about PQ core. Why it is interesting to have a PQ in a Flyback transformer ?

"Magnetics" manufacturer says : 
"PQ cores are designed specifically for switched-mode power supplies. This design provides an optimized ratio of volume to winding area and surface area. As a result, both maximum inductance and winding area are possible with a minimum core size. The cores provide maximum power output with minimum assembled transformer weight and volume, in addition, to taking up a minimum amount of area on the printed circuit board. This efficient design provides a more uniform cross-sectional area; thus cores tend to operate with fewer hot spots than with other designs. Typical applications include power transformers and power inductors."

Is this only for minimizing space at the price of lower efficiency ? (The board is clearly huge and there is a lot of space)

If you have any advice, it will be a pleasure to hear it !

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see a problem. Please link to the TI document and provide a link to the ferrite core set document you might consider.

Comment: RM and PQ cores are the types you see the most in high-volume ac-dc adapters for notebooks, though PQ are a bit more expensive than RMs I think.

Comment: What I wanted to highlight is the fact that the document written by TI is saying that PQ core is not suited for flyback transformer and the design of transformer that I have is made with a PQ core 
http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup127/slup127.pdf ...........
https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/ds/b65877a.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Verbal Kint ? (#KaiserSoze) ? Do you mean high density power per volume or high volume ? You mean PQ core is interesting in saving place/volume on PCB ? PQ core has a better ratio power/volume than other core ?